# Do you need to import React for using JSX in components?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a NextJS project, and I have some components.

When using JSX, IDE tells me to import React from 'React'.

However, if I don't do that, the page still works.

Why?

Comment: Then you dont need .jsx extension

Answer (score 1):

Summary: NextJS has the plugin https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx which adds the import automatically for you.

**More detailed explanation**

NextJS (Version 9 at this time) comes with its on babel configuration next/babel. 
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-babel-config

The following are the babel plugins preinstalled by nextjs

1. preset-env
2. preset-react
3. preset-typescript
4. plugin-proposal-class-properties
5. plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
6. plugin-transform-runtime styled-js

The plugin [preset-react](http://%20https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) bundles another plugin https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx which adds the React import for you. More examples are in the plugin page.